# AngularJS: Refresh angular scope outside of ng-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

OK, so I have a basic login page that when the user logs in I want to then display more details on the navbar at the top of the screen. When they click logout, this then goes away. This is working (in a way) however to get the navbar to change I need to refresh the page, which obviously does not happen when i just use routing to change what is in my ng-view.

When the user clicks 'log in' their username is stored in a service which is called using the login controller that is within the ng-view.

```
authService.SetUsername(user.Username);
```

However I want this to have an effect in my navbar controller which is outside the ng-view.

Here you can see in my trimmed down navbar controller how this is being used.

```
app.controller('navbarController', function ($scope, authService, $cookies, $location) {

    $scope.displayUsername = authService.GetUsername();

});
```

But `displayusername` is only changed when the page is refreshed and the controller is 'reloaded'.  How do I get this to change instantly when the service storing the username is updated?

Comment: Could you add the authService service code here to help you more?

Comment: You want refresh just scope? Can not you do refresh all page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can broadcast a login event:

```
.factory("authService", [
    "$rootScope",
    function ($rootScope) {
        return {
            login: function () {
                // do the login
                $rootScope.$broadcast("login-done");
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

and your controller:

```
app.controller('navbarController', function ($scope, $rootScope, authService, $cookies, $location) {

    $scope.displayUsername = authService.GetUsername();

    $rootScope.$on("login-done", function() {
        $scope.displayUsername = authService.GetUsername();
    });
});
```

Comment: Since he is broadcasting from the $rootScope, it can be listened to on $scope in controller. Not a big deal, just 1 less dependency in the controller. Not sure if either way is more efficient otherwise

Comment: Works like a charm. Had no idea about the broadcast service before.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create variable $rootScope.displayName.
2. Use {{ displayName }} in HTML markup for your navbar.
3. Up on success on login page, update $rootScope.displayName.
4. Praise AngularJS.

Usually, I recommend having object $rootScope.user where more information can be stored about user, not just displayName.